# make not visible asp

Tags: asp.net

I have a site that will show the priority of a user made in asp. 
If the user is seated it will show the user is seated in the room
if not then show nothing.
I can get it to show seated inside a red border but if not seated it shows the border still
I would like to make the border invisible  here is my code so far.

```
Text='<%# iif(Eval("Priority")=0, "Seated", nothing %>
```

Here is the entire code I am using a datalist that connects to a server

```
  <asp:DataList ID="DataList4" runat="server" CellPadding="0" 
                    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource4" CssClass="topcss" 
                    Width="363px" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" 
                    BorderWidth="3px" GridLines="Horizontal" >
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Testing&nbsp;
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Expr2Label" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Expr2") %>' />
                        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' />
                        ,<asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' />
                        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="PriorityLabel" runat="server" BorderColor="Red" 
                            BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" Text='<%# iif(Eval("Priority")=0, "Seated", nothing) %>' />
                        <br />
                    </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Visible='<%# Eval("Priority")="0" %>'
```

That code did what I wanted
If a person wasn't seated it will not show anything next to their name
If a person was seated it will show seated next to their name inside a red border

Answer (score 1):

Jose,

Assuming you have something like this

```
<a href='foo'><img src='img.jpg'/>Seated</a>
```

And when not seated like this

```
<a href='foo'><img src='img.jpg'/></a>
```

Then you can control the border by either removing the image tag, or setting some CSS properties in the image tag.

```
<a href='foo'><img class='noborder' src='img.jpg'/></a>
```

Comment: +1 - Just because you are trying to understand the incomprehensible.

Comment: guess I have to do something in JQuery to do it